# PowerBuilder overwrite txt file to make it tab separated

Tags: powerbuilder

i have an easy question but i m stack at the moment and i was wondering if anyone can help me out,

i need the part of code in PB that will overwrite a txt file and make it tab separated.

That is consider a insert.txt file with the following format

533#*0000000000007851*

594#*0000000000006937*

36#*0000000000005667*

....

and i want to overwrite it with PB code and make it like this

533 *0000000000007851*

594 *0000000000006937*

36  *0000000000005667*

......

so the # will be deleted and will become the tab...

I hope that you understand the question

Please some help i m so stack , any help would be really appreciated

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct but could be simpler.

1) import the file as single column

2) Parse the values in each row looking for the '#' similar to this:

```
integer li
string ls_a, ls_b, ls_rowvalue
FOR li = 1 TO dw_import.Rowcount()
  ls_rowvalue = dw_import.object.columnwithdata[li]
  ls_a = Right(ls_rowvalue, Pos(ls_rowvalue, "#") - 1)
  ls_b = Mid(ls_rowvalue, Pos(ls_rowvalue, "#") + 1)
  //put the values into a new datawindow
NEXT
dw_newvalues.Saveas("C:\temp\newstuff.txt)
```

The default 'saveas' type is Text! which is tab separated.

Comment: i managed to do it as you described but with my way .. that is lets say i import my file into a ds then i have the following code

Answer (score 0):

i think that i found the way, please correct me if i m wrong

1. insert all data in a datastore with importfile  in a single column
2. row by row then find the # and replace it with tab and then insert the 2 new values in another ds
3. exportfile

is the above correct ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   for li=1 to lds_cons_buffer.rowcount()

            //if the file is tab seperated
            ls_data1 = lds_cons_buffer.getitemstring(li, 'v_data1')     
            ls_data2 = lds_cons_buffer.getitemstring(li, 'v_data2')

            //if the file is not tab seperated but like this 533#0000000000007851....
            if isnull(ls_data2) and Match(ls_data1, "#") then
                    ll_length = Len(ls_data1)
                    ll_length_left = Pos(ls_data1, "#") -1  
                    ll_length_right  = ll_length - Pos(ls_data1, "#")
                    ls_data1_temp  = Left(ls_data1, ll_length_left)
                    ls_data2_temp  =Right(ls_data1, ll_length_right)
                    ls_data1 = ls_data1_temp
                    ls_data2 = ls_data2_temp
            end if
     next
```

Answer (score 0):

The ImportFile suggests win in terms of simplicity, but presuppose that you know the maximum length of each line, and that loading the entire file into memory twice (although this ignores the disk storage option on the DW/DS) isn't a problem.

For a minimal memory footprint, I'd consider FileOpen/FileRead functions on the source file, read the file in LineMode, parse each line (PFC has a global string replace function), and FileWrite the result to a temp file. Then, at the end, rename your source to a .BAK (or something like that... destroying someone's data...) and rename the temp file to the source file's name.

This option is definitely more work, but it's another road up the mountain. The better your map, the better chance you have of getting there.